# Dynamic chart title with Epplus

Tags: c#, excel, charts, epplus

I would like to know if there is a way I can set a chart title dynamically in Epplus.

Right now I am aware of the option:

`chart.Title.Text = "MyTitle";`

but I would like to be able to set the title dynamically based on a formula.

More specifically, I have this formula in my worksheet:

`workSheet.Names.AddFormula("GraphName", $"OFFSET(B12,0,GraphNbr-1)");`

where `GraphNbr` is an integer which can be chosen by the user in the Excel workbook via a dropdown list.

The formula returns what I would like to set as chart title depending on the choice of `GraphNbr`.

I would like to be able to set the chart title as the result of the formula, but I can't find a way to do it with Epplus (in the Excel worksheet I would just click on the title and then insert the formula in the formula bar).

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate some more? In what way do you mean dynamically?

Comment: Thanks, I added  more information in the post.

Comment: Can you do in real Excel?  May be you can if you use a Named range.